# While running flutter doctor I'm getting bash : permision denied

Tags: flutter

My flutter path directory : 
path : xxxx/apps/flutter/bin

While runnng flutter doctor Im getting
bash: xxxx/apps/flutter/bin/flutter: Permission denied

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: ubuntu 16.0 . I upgraded flutter. I got issues with the latest versions. So I degraded flutter to V1.2.1. From then I'm getting this issue

Comment: whats the output of `ls -l xxxx/apps/flutter/bin/flutter`?

Comment: Output is :  -rw-rw-r--

Comment: you need `-rwxr-xr-x`

Comment: But the path is not that

Comment: I changed the file permission and now when I'm running flutter doctor I'm getting

 /usr/bin/env: ‘bash\r’: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Then probably you have to assign rights for accessing that folder. Try this:

```
sudo chown -R $USER xxxx/apps/flutter
```

Comment: still getting same issue. Actually my flutter path is 
"xxx/apps/flutter/bin" but its showing permission denied path as 
"bash: xxx/apps/flutter/bin/flutter: Permission denied